# flip vertical using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to flip the div horizontally and vertically both. When I click first div the div flip horizontally and when I click second div it flip vertically.

```js
function flip_hori() {
    $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
}

function flip_verticle() {
    $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
 axis : 'x'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
  <div class="card" >
    <div class="front"><label onclick="flip_hori()">flip</label></div>
    <div class="back" ><label onclick="flip_verticle()">flip</label></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you set up a working example?

Comment: Your code in snippet not working??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831908/how-can-i-flip-a-div-when-an-image-within-that-div-is-clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this simply by using the plugin http://nnattawat.github.io/flip/

or can do it by

[How can I flip a Div when an image within that div is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831908/how-can-i-flip-a-div-when-an-image-within-that-div-is-clicked)

Comment: You should include an examle of code in your answer instead of just posting links. When the links stop working your answer is no more relevant.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.flipped {
    transform: scale(-1);
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(".card label").on("click", function () {
    $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="front">
        <label>flip</label>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
        <label>flip</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/toby3105/xjqaqdbo/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to toggle the following CSS classes in order to apply a flip effect.

Notes:

- The action is applied to each label as from your initial example.
- The following should work cross platform as custom browser specific prefixes are included.

Demo here:

https://jsfiddle.net/q2zgcn1w/

```
.flippedX {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    -ms-filter: fliph;
    filter: fliph;
    background-color:red;
}
.flippedY {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    -ms-filter: flipw;
    filter: flipw;
    background-color:green;
}


$("#flipX").on("click", function () {
    $('.card').toggleClass('flippedX');
});

$("#flipY").on("click", function () {
    $('.card').toggleClass('flippedY');
});
```